# How to elegantly pass variables to command

Tags: loops, sed, grep, genbank

I have a set of commands that currently work with one file:

```
sed -n -e '/ABC/,/LOCUS/ p' mainfile.gbk | sed -e '$ d' >temp1
sed '/     source/,/     gene/{/     gene/!d}' temp1 >temp2
grep -v "     gene" temp2 >temp3
grep -v "                     /locus_tag" temp3 >temp4
sed 's/product/locus_tag/g' temp4 >ABC.txt
echo "DONE" >>ABC.txt
rm temp*
```

(I know, not very efficient but works for me). Shortly what it does: it outputs lines from string `ABC` to line `LOCUS` from file `mainfile.gbk`, then a couple of `sed` & `grep` commands to make the file parsable, and finally writes everything to a new file `ABC.txt`.

Now I want to iterate that command over a list of strings, i.e.

`list.txt`

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

so that each line from `list.txt` is taken and a assigned to a variable, then the commands are run and finally for each line in `list.txt` one file is outputted.

I thought of putting the commands around a `while read line` loop, but somehow the assignment of the variables does not work/they are not passed to the commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that the text is formatted as a single column (with no comments or blank lines or anything), you could use a for loop like this.

```
for token in `cat list.txt`
do
    sed -n -e "/$token/,/LOCUS/ p" mainfile.gbk | sed -e '$ d' >temp1
    sed '/     source/,/     gene/{/     gene/!d}' temp1 >temp2
    grep -v "     gene" temp2 >temp3
    grep -v "                     /locus_tag" temp3 >temp4
    sed 's/product/locus_tag/g' temp4 >$token.txt
    echo "DONE" >>$token.txt
    rm temp*
done
```

Comment: See: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Ok, I can see why you'd prefer `while` over `for`.  However, it only matters if there are multiple tokens per line, which is not true in the question.

Comment: `$token` won't be expanded in single quotes, so this doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting, that's news to me.  Is there any reason why we can't just use double quotes here?